# cad_alunos.php (Formulário de Cadastro de Alunos php)

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou tendo um problema na minha aplicação de php pois está me aparecendo assim:
Qndo eu seleciono cadastro deficiente Visual e continuo o cadastro do formulário e clico em cadastrar ele simplesmente não funciona e me manda esta mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me ajuda a resolver este problema pf!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mqvhWjSH/?e=1

Comment: Segue o formulário de cad_alunno(formulário de cadastro de aluno.php)

Comment: Mauro em que linha pf!

Comment: Poderia colocar o código fonte na perguntar?

Comment: Eu coloquei via pastebin.com

Comment: Assim Mauro:
                <form name="form" novalidate class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="processa/proc_cad_aluno.php">

Comment: Vlw funcionou obrigado

Comment: Adicionei como resposta para ajudar a quem tenha a mesma dúvida futuramente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é adicionar o `novalidate` no seu formulário, visto que essa não é uma das formas mais recomendadas.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate  method="POST" action="processa/proc_cad_aluno.php">
```

Comment: Estou tendo outro problema com relação a cadastro de País Trabalho, quando quero editar me mostra essa mensagem:
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\IBC\login\editar_aluno.php on line 699

Comment: Dai essa é outra questão. Se essa resposta te ajudou, marque como melhor resposta para ajudar os outros que venham a ter essa dúvida. Referente a esse erro, você deve fazer outra pergunta.